# How can I see what the current android layout looks like for debugging purposes?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android application, I frequently add and remove parts of my layout. Is there a way I can log or capture the layout at specific points? I want to see the way my buttons and layouts are nested to ensure it is as I want it to be at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the hierarchyviewer tool that comes with the SDK, in the platform-tools directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can take screenshots using DDMS, or in Eclipse, view the layout as you create it..